# PHP Get root directory of website

Tags: php, html

I am making a site and I need to get the "root" directory of the site. Like if the filestructure was similar to

```
CloudShop
    \-internal
        \-js
            ...
        \-inc
            inc.all.php
    index.php
    \-login
        login.php
        loginError.php
    page.php
```

In inc.all.php I am getting all the pages in the database so I can display them in the navigation bar and I am setting the links like `<a href="page.php?id=XXX>PAGE_TITLE</a>` However, when I click on one of the page links from login.php, it takes me to `/CloudShop/login/page.php?id=XXX`. I want it to take me to `/CloudShop/page.php?id=XXX`.

Comment: If you want it to link to `/CloudShop/page.php?id=XXX` use the following link in the `href`: `/CloudShop/page.php?id=XXX`. Wow such genius. Much relative. fantastilous. Great win

Answer (score 2):

You can use path-absolute URIs. Suppose you had at `http://www.example.com/shop/login/login.php`:

```
<a href="/shop/page.php?id=1">page</a>
```

The resolved URI would be `http://www.example.com/shop/page.php?id=1`.

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion: Try the PHP Magic constants:

```
__DIR__
```